# CSS animation speed control

Tags: css, animation

[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/Serhiicss/pen/dOqbXp)

```
<pre>
.parent
  border: 1px solid tomato
  height: 300px
  margin: 0 auto
  margin-top: 30px
  width: 80%

.box
  width: 50px
  height: 50px
  position: absolute
  animation-name: falling
  animation-iteration-count: infinite


.box-1
  background-color: lightblue
  right: 60vw
  animation-duration: 6s
  @keyframes falling
    0%
      top: -10vh
    100%
      top: 90vh

.box-2
  background-color: lightgreen
  right: 70vw
  animation-duration: 8s
  @keyframes falling
    0%
      top: -10vh
    100%
      top: 90vh
</pre>
```

As you can see in the demo, the animation speed of the cube is slowing down the closer it gets to the bottom.

I'd like to make animation the same speed during the fall.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [`animation-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) in CSS is [ease](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function#ease) - accelerate in the start, slow after the middle. You need a [linear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function#linear) timing function, that has a constant speed.

Change the box timing function to linear ([pen](http://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/mOGddj)):

```
.box
  width: 50px
  height: 50px
  position: absolute
  animation-name: falling
  animation-iteration-count: infinite
  animation-timing-function: linear
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use animation function `linear`. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 80%;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: falling;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  right: 60vw;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
@keyframes falling {
  0% {
    top: -10vh;
  }
  100% {
    top: 90vh;
  }
}
.box-2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  right: 70vw;
  animation-duration: 8s;
}
@keyframes falling {
  0% {
    top: -10vh;
  }
  100% {
    top: 90vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!